# What do you call a person or community that grants refuge?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm wondering if there is a common term for a person or group of people who grant refuge.

I understand that a refuge is a *place* that provides protection or shelter of some sort, but it is often the case that *someone* has to grant that refuge.

That *someone* might be a relative giving their niece/nephew a place to stay while they get back on their feet or a nation exercising its sovereignty by granting asylum to political refugees.

Is there a name for such a person or community?

Comment: "In a modern context," an individual person does not grant refuge or asylum, a government does. Of course, that government is composed of people, but they are working as its agents. Could you [edit] your post to provide an example scenario? Are you referring, for example, to a figure like the bishop in *Les Misérables*?

Comment: We'd normally say *He **gave/provided sanctuary***. But I can't really see a problem with [Even the mean ones seemed to warm to her, like she was a sanctuary](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22like+she+was+a+sanctuary%22) if *she herself* embodies the "protection or shelter" being provided. Bear in mind many (most?) countries *automatically* accept "refugees", so all you're talking about there is some government functionary who in theory has no decision-making powers whatsoever.

Comment: See https://www.worldrelief.org/blog/who-is-a-refugee-and-what-do-they-go-through-to-get-to-the-u-s?gclid=CjwKCAiAjanRBRByEiwAKGyjZRoGrLDfUsH2XpTcCSKigSB2UPOive211ZCAR836iGo7YaboFj1TBBoC_M8QAvD_BwE on obtaining refugee status in the United States.  Finding a specific sponsor is close to a last step.

Comment: @choster I've edited the post to include examples and I've reformulated the question slightly. Hopefully the question is a bit clearer now! I'd like to emphasise that an **individual** can also grant refuge in a less legal sense. Also you're right, the comment about 'modern context' was misleading.

Comment: A community that grants refuge could be called *a refuge*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah I imagine I would use a similar phrase but I was wondering if there is a single word that might epitomise such a person or group. Also, you're absolutely right! There isn't a problem with a person embodying a refuge. And about the government functionary, the term would be more aimed at the legislators and policy makers of the country, people in the executive positions.

Comment: Why do you think the same word would apply to a state accepting refugees and a householder giving someone a place to stay?

Comment: Please show us a sentence indicating how you would use this noun. Single-word-requests are not for words to put into a dictionary next to a definition, but for a word that will be put to use, hence the requirement that there be a sample sentence with a blank where the word would go.  And not just a perfunctory sentence like "He was a ________".

Answer (score 3):

Legal texts typically use the term *harborer* ([*harbourer*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/harbourer#English), UKSE)

Comment: A person might be harboured if they are a **fugitive** from the state. It's not usually used for a **refugee**, at least in BrE. (That is, *harbouring* is wrong as it prevents the fugitive from being brought to justice. Granting asylum has a positive connotation.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider calling the person who takes a refugee into their home a **host**. The place is simply termed a **place of asylum**, where *asylum* is used in the sense of the definition below. (The country can also be called a **host**.)

> **host** *noun*
> 1 A person who receives or entertains other people as guests.
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/host)
>
> **asylum** *noun*
> 1 (also **political asylum**) *mass noun* The protection granted by a state to someone who has left their home country as a political refugee.
> ‘she applied for asylum and was granted refugee status’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/asylum)

Here's a wikipedia entry that uses the term *country of asylum* in this manner:

- By country of asylum
  [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_refugee_population#By_country_of_asylum)

Here are a couple of examples where the word *host* is used in this context:

- Becoming a host is an opportunity for you to show solidarity to people in need and help in a very real and practical way.
  [- Refugees Welcome](https://www.refugeeswelcome.org.au/)
- But there's also a lot of relief and pleasure for the host and guest. Living with refugees neutralises fear and loathing.
  [- The Sydney Morning Herald](http://www.smh.com.au/comment/how-you-can-offer-a-home-to-a-refugee-20150929-gjxhnc.html)

Here are a couple of examples where the word *host* is used as a verb. This is arguably a case of [zero derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)), and we can call the person or place doing the
hosting a *host*.

- Due to the incredible surge of interest in people offering their homes to host a refugee, Alyan’s List organisation has been developed in partnership with Australian Homestay Network to implement a placement program.
  [- Australian Refugee](http://www.australianrefugee.org/our-syrian-response/) (note: *host* here is used as a verb)
- Ten countries host half of world's refugees
  [- News Grid](http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2016/10/ten-countries-host-world-refugees-report-161004042014076.html)

Answer (score 0):

Given that new "sanctuary cities" are gaining new traction, this is a very timely and relevant question. While "harborer" and "host" may serve, is it time to introduce "sanctuarist" to denote someone who actively runs a sanctuary or is active in a sanctuary movement or who promotes the provision of sanctuary to those seeking it?

Comment: Good answers don't generally end with a question mark. This is a Q&A site and not a discussion forum, so all answers should be directly related the original question. If you want to ask a new question, you can use the "Ask Question" button on the homepage to create a new thread (and you can link back to this).